# Strava - How to detect pause in run/activity

Tags: api, strava

Is there a way to detect a user pausing a run/activity within the strava API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Get Activity Streams (`getActivityStreams`)](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Streams-getActivityStreams) you can obtain differents [`StreamSet`](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-models-StreamSet) from your activity: in order to detect pause I think you can analyze `CadenceStream` or `MovingStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Pauses are not available in the Strava API and can not be extracted consistently through algorithmic processing of the available fields. Moreover, the data contained in the API's streams collection can not be processed in a way which will arrive at the summary distance or time of the run.

The MovingStream contains a bit field which does not flag pauses, but instead (presumably) flags points where the athlete stopped moving. Although, that said, this field can not be used to arrive at the Moving Time by summing up the time values where this flag is true.